# "select all" and "remove" buttons in "card browser /multi row card" tools Powerbi

Tags: powerbi

Is there any possibility to keep "select all" and "remove" buttons in "card

browser /multi row card" tools in Powerbi ?

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: [Please refer to this image](https://ibb.co/mua8kS) .Actually I need this kind of visual.I tried with card browser and multi-row card visuals.but I could not  get that type of facility.Is there any other visuals which reflects.

Comment: @swapna It looks like a customized one. Try working around chiclet slicers and bookmarks to get something like that. To get chiclet slicer:- **https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380756?tab=Overview**